# How to generate sequence with maxmum value in existing sequence

Tags: sql, sequence

```
EMP_NO                 EMP_NAME   
---------------------- ---------- 
1                      mohan      
2                      ram        
3                      sysytem    
4                      chandra    
5                      screen     
6                      admin      
7                      manajor    
8                      project    
9                      keybord    
10                     mouse      
11                     monitor
```

Using  max value in above table how to generate a sequence

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Can you give an example of the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create sequence lets name it SEQ.
2. While inserting into table

   INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (EMP_NO,EMP_NAME)
   VALUES (SELECT SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL, ...... );

Otherwise (No need to create sequence)

```
select max(EMP_NO)+1 from EMP_TABLE
```

Comment: so please query for that

Comment: insert into EMP_TABLE(EMP_NO,EMP_NAME)VALUES(SELECT max(EMP_NO) from EMP_TABLE,'MyNAME');

Comment: i want query using sequence

Comment: Step 1 :create sequence SEQ;  Step 2: INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (EMP_NO,EMP_NAME) VALUES (SELECT SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL,'My Name' );

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to start with max(emp_no) + 1?
If yes, use this

```
DECLARE
    EX  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT
          MAX ( EMP_NO )
          + 1
    INTO
          EX
    FROM
          EMP;

    IF EX > 0
    THEN
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE SQ_NAME';
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
                NULL;
        END;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
               'CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_NAME INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '
            || EX
            || ' NOCYCLE CACHE 20 NOORDER';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: i want query in sql not in pl/sql

Comment: Add the number as a parameter SELECT
   MAX ( EMP_NO )
   + 1 AS EX
FROM
   EMP;

CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_NAME
 INCREMENT BY 1
 START WITH  &EX NOCYCLE CACHE 20 NOORDER;

Comment: You cannot do it without PLSQL block or without passing as a parameter. Try to understand the limitations and constraints.